# Homework help: Vector functions

Tags: vector-bundles

i need help with an assignment:

We have 2 vector functions, described below (Its a screenshot from my mathcad document, cant format it here)

[image]

I need to calculate at what "t" value the 2 functions are closest to each other

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, cant seem to edit the post because it was migrated here, so il just post the a clearer image, without the variables

[image]